# Change Zsh theme in Android Studio

Tags: terminal, zsh, theme, oh-my-zsh

I've recently jumped ship to `zsh` and I'm using the [Oh my Zsh!](http://ohmyz.sh) theme `blinks`. It looks very nice in the OSX Terminal, but it looks very bad in Android Studio's terminal.

**So my question is** is there a way to check that this session has been opened in Android Studio and not in the OSX Terminal and change the `zsh` theme according to that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think this is just an issue with Intellij in general. I posted [this](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/455995?tstart=0) on their forums a while ago. Would love to know the answer myself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but it's easy enough to just run a little script to change 'PS1' from whatever to whatever. Looks like you want to change the background color mostly.

Comment: As a sort of kludge, you may try traversing PID tree starting from your parent process ($PPID) up to the very PID 1. If you see there's `java`, switch the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has given you an answer, I'm trying despite having completely different software. So this is a generic answer on how to do it with *any* software. There are two approaches that come to mind:

### 1. Different environments

Open Terminal, and run `env > env.terminal`. Open Android Studio, and run `env > env.studio`. Now, in either terminal, you can run `diff -dby --suppress-common-lines env.terminal env.studio` (if Mac OS X diff has those options; if not `-U1` works well enough).

As an example, here is the difference between `xterm` and `konsole` on my Linux box (note: spacing modified to fit on the page):

```
                                   > PROFILEHOME=
                                   > SHELL_SESSION_ID=1e8d5ab2d16641668485f991a1beffe3
                                   > QSG_RENDER_LOOP=
                                   > COLORTERM=truecolor
XTERM_SHELL=/bin/bash              <
                                   > KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION=/Sessions/1
XTERM_VERSION=XTerm(327)           | KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW=/Windows/1
TERM=xterm                         <
                                   > TERM=xterm-256color
                                   > KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=:1.1514
                                   > QMLSCENE_DEVICE=
                                   > KONSOLE_PROFILE_NAME=Default
                                   > COLORFGBG=15;0
WINDOWID=83886094                  | WINDOWID=115343366
XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xauth-1000-_0      | XAUTHORITY=/home/anthony/.Xauthority
KDED_STARTED_BY_KDEINIT=1          <
XTERM_LOCALE=en_US.UTF-8           <
```

Some of that stuff is clearly noise from how I launched the two different terminals. But others are not. If I wanted something only in XTerm, then `if [ -n "$XTERM_VERSION" ]` would seem to be a pretty good way to do that. Similarly, for Konsole, `$KONSOLE_PROFILE_NAME` would be a good one (and probably a few of the others, too).

### 2. Different parent processes

A shell knows its own process ID, it can be accessed via `$$`. POSIX also has `$PPID` to get the parent PID directly, so I suspect you have that in zsh too. If not, `ps` can get it for you: `ppid=$(ps -o ppid= $$)`. You can then get the command run, also with ps:

```
xterm:~$ ps -o args= $PPID
/usr/bin/xterm

konsole:~$ ps -o args= $PPID
/usr/bin/konsole
```

(You can try `-o comm=` as well).

In a shell script, it'd look something like:

```shell
ppid=$(ps -o ppid= $$)   # if you don't have PPID for some reason
if [ "$(ps -o args= $ppid)" = "/usr/bin/xterm" ]; then
  echo "do xterm stuff"
fi
```

If you need to go further up the process tree, you can use `ps` to get the parent's parent, etc.